# jpa/hibernate load eagerly whole chain in auto relashionship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eager-loading, entitygraph

I'm using JPA Entity Graphs to eagerly load relationships.

But, my problem is:

The relation is an auto-relationship like this:

```
public class X{

     ...

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "foreign_key")
     protected @Getter @Setter X parent;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
     private @Getter @Setter Set<X> children;
}
```

So, when I get the object X from the database, the children come loaded too. This is right. But, when I get the first object of children Set and get their children, hibernate do execute another query in the database.

My entity class is anotated with this:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "cobranca-com-lancamentos-com-filhos",
        attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "children")
        }
    )
```

and my search is like this:

```
em.createQuery("FROM X WHERE id = " + id).setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", em.getEntityGraph("cobranca-com-lancamentos-com-filhos")).getSingleResult();
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to **eagerly** load the children. But within the code you explicitly set `FetchType.LAZY` - so do you want to load *eagerly* or *lazy*?

Because you use hibernate, you'll get a proxy for the children. The first time you use the Set (is it with `size()` or anything else) the children are loaded **LAZY** as you defined it with `FetchType.LAZY`.

Comment: I want to load eagerly just in that specific query. Because of that, I'm using JPA Named Entity Graph. When I use the children Set of X object, hibernate don't consult the database, like I said, this is rigth, I want this. But when I get an element of children Set and iterate over their children Set, hibernate consult the data base, and this is what I don't want, understand?